# Error when running Fortran program (forrtl: severe (157): Program Exception - access violation)

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a C program that has a function named `get_name`. This function returns a string (i.e. `char *`) and changes the argument `size` (passed to it) with the size of the string:

```
char *get_name(int &size)
{
     *size = strlen(name);   // name is a C global variable declared as a char *
     return name;
}
```

I have created the following Fortran module to be able to call the C function `get_name`:

```
MODULE X

    USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_intptr_t

    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTERFACE

        TYPE(c_ptr) FUNCTION get_name_(size) BIND(C, name = "get_name")
            USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_int, c_ptr
            INTEGER(c_int), INTENT(OUT) :: size
        END FUNCTION

    END INTERFACE

    CONTAINS

        FUNCTION get_name()
            USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding, ONLY: c_int, c_char, c_f_pointer, c_ptr, c_associated
            !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: get_name
            CHARACTER(LEN = :), ALLOCATABLE :: get_name
            INTEGER(c_int) :: size
            TYPE(c_ptr) :: c_string

            c_string = get_name_(size)

            IF (c_associated(c_string)) THEN
                BLOCK
                    CHARACTER(KIND = c_char, LEN = size), POINTER :: f_string
                    CALL c_f_pointer(c_string, f_string)
                    get_name = f_string
                END BLOCK
            ELSE
                get_name = ""
            END IF

        END FUNCTION

END MODULE
```

I can successfully compile this Fortran module using IFORT 2016 in Windows, IFORT 2016 in Linux, and gfortran in Linux.

To test things, I have created a short Fortran program:

```
PROGRAM Test

    USE X

    WRITE(*, *) "Name: ", get_name()

END PROGRAM
```

I can successfully compile this Fortran program using IFORT 2016 in Windows, IFORT 2016 in Linux, and gfortran in Linux.

Now, when running the program it works well in IFORT 2016 for Linux, gfortran in Linux, but not in IFORT 2016 for Windows. It actually gives the following error:

```
 forrtl: severe (157): Program Exception - access violation
```

Any idea how this error can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

I assume your C function is `char *get_name(int *size)` instead of using a C++ reference.

Then this code works here on Windows and Linux with Ifort 16 and gcc-6.3.1 or Visual Studio 2015.

Please add your used C compiler and command lines to compile the code. I used:

`cl -c testc.c && ifort -c testf.f /extend-source:132 && ifort testm.f testf.obj testc.obj /extend-source:132 && testm.exe`

Btw: If you are using this function in parallel code I would suggest to avoid the block construct - I had bad experience using this in parallel (OpenMP) code with Ifort 16.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. Please suggest request for additional info or comments that the code works for you in the comments section. BTW, most likely it will work (although not guaranteed) the same even with the C++ reference.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF for your suggestion but unfortunately I'm not yet allowed to add comments - should I delete my answer? I also thought a C++ reference should work but then the body of the function is wrong and I don't know a standard which defines that a C++ reference should behave like a C pointer for every compiler.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the body is wrong then. You can put that into the answer and keep it, that is valid stuff.